# wait does not wait

Tags: shell, process, exit

If i have a file called `myprogram` containing

```
sleep 200
date
```

Run this in the background:

```
$ sh myprogram &
```

i want to know when `myprogram` has completed by using `wait` command

```
$ cat >notify
wait PID
echo "Program completed"
$ sh notify &
```

`PID` is the process ID given from third command, my problem is that the message "program completed" printed on the terminal immediately after the last command,why wait does not wait? , i am using ubuntu 11.10

Comment: I'm pretty sure `wait` can only wait for *child* processes, which means it must be run in the *parent* shell, not a separate one like you are doing with the `sh wait`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The child-parent relationship gets ruined by all the '&' involved.

The `wait(2)` system call, which the `wait` builtin is apparently based on, will only work for a direct child PID of the process that calls `wait(2)`.

When you invoke `sh myprogram &`, you run `sh` as a child of the interactive shell.

When you invoke `sh notify &`, that `sh` is a child of the interactive shell.

So the second `sh` has no direct parent relationship with the first `sh`, and `wait` will not work.

This won't even work if you invoke `sh myprogram &; sh notify;` either, because the `wait` command is invoked by a child of the interactive shell.

What does work for me is this: `sh myprogram &; wait`  The `wait` command causes the interactive shell (parent of the `sh` invoked explicitly) to hang around until the `sh` exits.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific example, it's best to just run `wait` in the main shell as Bruce's answer shows, but if you had some alternate situation where you can't do that - for example, if you need to run `myprogram` as a foreground process, or if it's a daemon without a controlling terminal -
you can use a program I've written called [pwait](https://github.com/diazona/pwait) that will wait for an arbitrary process to finish. To use it in this example, after running

```
$ sh myprogram
```

you would obtain the process ID of `myprogram` somehow, and then in `notify`, instead of `wait` you'd use

```
pwait PID
```

My version of `pwait` is Linux-only, for now. If you're running FreeBSD, they have [their own implementation](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/master/bin/pwait) which appears to be available as a standard utility. You can also sort of fudge it using `ps` to repeatedly check whether the command has finished, as in [this shell script](https://github.com/wting/pwait) (although that doesn't tell you the command's exit code, in case that's relevant).